# possible to add additional field into all querysets? django

Tags: python, django, django-models, lambda, django-queryset

I have a `querysets` in a model for example

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=256)
    ageMin = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ageMax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def age(self):
      low = self.ageMin
      high = self.ageMax
      if low and high:
          return str(low) + ' - ' + str(high)
      if low:
          return str(low)
      if high:
        return str(high)
```

let's say I have a queryset to get all return of `ModelA`
I actually want to add a field into all queryset such as a field named `age_gap` which is the `def age` from the model itself so each queryset will also have an extra field named `gap_gap` not just `name, ageMin, ageMax`

I tried something like the following but not working though.

```
all_q = ModelA.objects.filter()
qs = map(lambda x: x.update({'age_gap': x.age()}), all_q)
```

the above doesn't work

so I thought of trying something like
    for q in all_q:
        q['age_gap'] = q.age()

of course this gives me error too

Can someone please give me a hand on how this can be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There anything wrong with just using that age function when you want to reference it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@property` or `@cached_property`

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=256)
    ageMin = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ageMax = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

    def age(self):
      low = self.ageMin
      high = self.ageMax
      if low and high:
          return str(low) + ' - ' + str(high)
      if low:
          return str(low)
      if high:
        return str(high)

    @property
    def age_gap(self):
        return self.age()
```